# I can't assign an object to an object array

Tags: c++, memory, copy-constructor

I just wrote my first copy constructor and copy operator, and I'm trying to assign an object instance to an array like so:

```
Agent agent = Agent(navmesh, rb, m_maxPathSize);
Agent tmp = agent; // DEBUG
m_agents[idx] = agent;
```

The copy constructor seems to be working fine, since `tmp` is a perfect copy of `agent` (with a newly assigned `m_path` pointer). But when I assign `agent` to `m_agents[idx]`, the latter consists of what I'd expect from the default constructor (`m_path == 0`, `m_alive == false`).

My constructors look like this:

```
Agent() { m_path = 0; m_alive = false; };
Agent::Agent(NavMeshNavigator* navmesh, RigidBody* rb, int maxPathSize)
    : m_rb(rb), m_navmesh(navmesh), m_maxPathCount(maxPathSize)
{
    m_path = new float3[maxPathSize];
};
Agent::Agent(const Agent &a)
{
    memcpy(this, &a, sizeof(Agent));
    if (m_path)
    {
        float3* oldptr = m_path;
        m_path = new float3[m_maxPathCount];
        memcpy(m_path, oldptr, m_maxPathCount * sizeof(float3));
    }
}
Agent& Agent::operator=(const Agent &a) { return Agent(a); }
Agent::~Agent() { if (m_path) delete[] m_path; };

...

protected:
   float3* m_path;
   bool m_alive = true;
```

The constructor allocates memory for `m_path` using `new[]`, the destructor frees it with `delete[]`, the copy operator calls the copy constructor, and the copy constructor first memcopies the original before allocating a new `m_path` array.

In my test case, `idx == 0`, so that can't be it. I originally used `malloc` instead of `new[]` but got the same results. I'd say the problem is in my copy constructor/operator since I have no experience with that, but then why does it work perfectly on `tmp`?

EDIT:
The m_agents array is declared and destroyed like this:

```
NavMeshAgents(int maxAgents, int maxAgentPathSize)
        : m_maxAgents(maxAgents), m_maxPathSize(maxAgentPathSize)
    {
        m_agents = new Agent[maxAgents];
    };
    ~NavMeshAgents() { if (m_agents) delete[] m_agents; m_agents = 0; };
```

Comment: How have you declared/defined the `m_agents` array?

Comment: Your assignment operator is broken. Not only you don't assign anything to the member variables in it, you also return a reference to a temporary (which shouldn't compile to begin with). Why do you do all this pointer juggling anyway? If you replaced `m_path` with a `std::vector`, you wouldn't need the copy constructor and assignment, and the destructor...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thought the operator= should return an object instance, and since Agent is an instance, it should be returned correctly right? `tmp` had no problem with it.
Edit: I need to hand out Agent pointers

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica I edited the original post

Comment: `Agent tmp = agent` is not an assignment, it's a copy constructor invocation.

Comment: `memcpy(this, &a, sizeof(Agent));` Which learning resource recommended this? Which book are you using?

Comment: @Evg [Start here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/155739). We're having some political troubles here lately.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I'm not using any resources. I've been using C++ for about 3 years without extensive formal education. What would you recommend doing instead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if `Agent tmp = agent` uses the copy constructor, shouldn't `m_agents[idx] = agent` also use the copy constructor?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I mean what do you recommend instead of `memcpy`?

Comment: `m_agents[idx] = agent` is just a syntactic sugar for `m_agents[idx].operator=(agent)`.

Comment: @Jornam No, in your second case, the `Agent` object has already been constructed and you're assigning it a value; in the first case, what *looks like* an assignment is, in fact, an initialization of a new object.

Comment: @Jornam Nope, that one is a copy assignment. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2365027dc9ba6407

Comment: @Evg I understand now, I can see the array assignment calling operator= in the debugger. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of `memcpy` just assign members manually.

Comment: @Evg But many are protected and private, so I can't access them.

Comment: You can. Try it. ;)

Comment: @Evg ...well how about that, it works. Still, it would be a pain to keep adding statements to the copy constructor as I keep adding members. And I don't see why memcpy would be bad tbh.

Comment: Because object's representation in memory is not guaranteed to consist only of its data members. What if it had virtual functions, for example? See *Notes* here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Answer (score 0):

As @Evg @HolyBlackCat and @Adrian-Reinstate-Monica explained in the comments, `new[]` calls the default constructor for all its members. `Agent tmp = agent` calls the copy constructor, whereas `tmp = agent` would've called the assignment operator (`tmp.operator=(agent)`). My assignment operator was wrong, it should initialize `this` (and then return `*this` rather than return an instance.

Comment: It returns `*this` to facilitate chaining `a = b = c`, mimicking fundamental types. If you don't need it, `operator=` can be declared as `void operator=(...)`.